# Read columns from Parquet in GCS without reading the entire file?

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage, parquet, pyarrow

Reading a parquet file from disc I can choose to read only a few columns (I assume it scans the header/footer, then decides). Is it possible to do this remotely (such as via Google Cloud Storage?)

We have 100 MB parquet files with about 400 columns and we have a use-case where we want to read 3 of them, and show them to the user. The user can choose which columns.

Currently we download the entire file, and then filter it but this takes time.

Long term we will be putting it into Google BigQuery and the problem will be solved

More specifically we use Python with either  pandas or PyArrow and ideally would like to use those (either with a GCS backend or manually getting the specific data we need via a wrapper). This runs in Cloud Run so we would prefer to not use Fuse, although that is certainly possible.

I intend to use Python and pandas/pyarrow as the backend for this, running in Cloud Run (hence why data size matter, because 100MB download to disk actually means 100MB downloaded to RAM)

We use `pyarrow.parquet.read_parquet` with `to_pandas()` or `pandas.read_parquet`.

Comment: Yes, you can.  You can perform a partial read of a GCS object.  Be aware of the tradeoffs, GCS has good throughput, but high latency.  Usually, reading 100 MiB takes less than 500 ms, while a single read takes several milliseconds (usually more than 10, but don't quote me on that)  to start.  For 3 columns the tradeoffs are good, as you increase the count of columns a full read may work better.

Comment: If you’d like more specific advice, please specify a language and framework, and provide code you’re using. For example, in python, the gcsfs package can be used to seamlessly reference  gcs parquet files using the same syntax.

Comment: Good point, I rushed the post a little. Added that we use Python with PyArrow or pandas

Comment: @MichaelDelgado for some reason I was under the impression that gcsfs didn’t do what I need, but looks like a good fit. Feel free to post this as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Can you edit the post to include your intended usage and correct the tags? Otherwise we have to make up an example which may or may not apply to your use case. Better for us to answer a specific use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.read_parquet` function has `columns` argument to read a subset of columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The community would appreciate if you would extend your answer to give more context to improve it -- how exactly can the described functionality used to resolve the asked question?

Comment: Yes, but you still would have needed to download the entire file from GCS?

Comment: You can pass GCP cloud storage path into the read_parquet function. Like - `pandas.read_parquet("gs://xxxx/yy/zzz", columns=4)` . You will have to install `pandas-gbq` before.