# Use gcsfs and pyarrow/pandas to read specific columns from file on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, pyarrow

I'm trying to use `gcsfs` together with pyarrow or Pandas to read from a file from GCS. However the file is quite massive, and I only want to select a small subset of columns.

Based on my tests, it looks like gcsfs downloads the entire file regardless of columns I specify through Pyarrow or Pandas. I haven't found a good way to verify that yet, but Activity Monitoring shows roughly the same amount of network traffic, and it takes the same time regardless of what columns I specify.

```
import gcsfs
import pyarrow.parquet

gs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(
    project='project',
    token=credentials
)
columns = ['COLUMN_1']
arrow_df = pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset('gs://large/file.parq', filesystem=gs)
df = arrow_df.read(columns).to_pandas()
```

```
with gs.open('gs://large/file.parq', 'rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_parquet(f, columns=columns)
```

Is there a way to read only a single column from a Parquet file via GCS? This might be simply impossible, or maybe that's what happening and it just happens to take the same amount of time.

Figured I'd ask :) Long term yes, the data will be in Big Query instead

Regards,
Niklas

PS: This is very close to my previous question [Read columns from Parquet in GCS without reading the entire file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75339463/read-columns-from-parquet-in-gcs-without-reading-the-entire-file), but much more direct in the actual question.